# How to use WriteProcessMemory (WPM) to replace strings?

Tags: c++, string, readprocessmemory

I am trying to write a simple code to replace a string in a program by another using WPM and I am able to make it work, but only partly. This is part of the code I used to get the result.

```
string strWrite;
cin >> strWrite;
strWrite = strWrite + "\0";
if (WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPVOID) reqdAddr, &strWrite[0], strWrite.size(), NULL) == false)
    {
        cout << "WriteProcessMemory failed. GetLastError = " << dec << GetLastError() << endl;
        system("pause");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
```

When I try to replace the original string `DefaultString` with `blabla`, the result I get is `blablatString`. I have tried things like replacing `strWrite.size()` by `strWrite.size() + 1` and realized that the result changes to `blabla String`. I need help replacing the entire string and not just the part of it.

Comment: You have to fill the difference in character length with \0

Comment: Which string format does the target process use? If it keeps track of the length seperately (like pascal strings or some c++ strings do) then you need to replace the size field of that string too

Comment: the string is std::string, so i guess, i will have to ask for the length of the string first using ReadProcessMemory()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If (as appears to be the case) the target string is stored as a std::string then this approach is not going to work.  These have an internal structure that programmers are not supposed to be privy to (unless you go digging around in the header file) and the code you have there is not taking account of that.  And even if you do, the next version of the compiler is probably going to break your code.

So consider instead (if you can) storing the target string as a simple C string.  Overwriting it is then straightforward just so long as you don't run off the end and you add a terminating nul.  I would do this explicitly - don't assume that the source string is nul-terminated, it may not be.  Or use `std::string.c_str()` and copy `size() + 1` bytes from that.

Comment: I am only trying out the function here, and yes, a C string works perfectly fine. I was only looking for a solution for std::string. Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Well I'm sure you can do it for `std::string` if (a) you know the internal layout of such objects _in the target process_, and (b) you can figure out enough about how they work to know which bits to patch.  Personally, I wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

std::string is a container that managed a char array on the back end.

As it stands right now, on x86 if the string you want to write is the same size or less than the current string, you can perform this with relative ease but it is not recommended.

offset 0x14 of the container is the size of the array
if the char array is less than 15 characters, the array is stored at offset 0x4
if the char array is greater than 15 characters, this offset is turned into a pointer to the dynamic array elsewhere

So you read the size of the array, then write to the correct address depending on it's size.  This code will do that and output "goodbye m8"

```
void WriteExternalString(HANDLE hProc, BYTE* addr, char* newstr)
{

    unsigned int arraySize;
    //Get the size of the array, offset 0x14 is the size of the array
    ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (BYTE*)(addr + 0x14), &arraySize, sizeof(arraySize), 0);

    if (arraySize > 15)
    {
        uintptr_t addrOfCharArray;
        //dereference the pointer in the second member variable to get the dynamic address of the array
        ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (BYTE*)(addr + sizeof(void*)), &addrOfCharArray, sizeof(void*), 0);

        //Write the buffer to the array, +1 to get the null terminator
        WriteProcessMemory(hProc, (BYTE*)(addrOfCharArray), newstr, strlen(newstr) + 1, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        WriteProcessMemory(hProc, (BYTE*)(addr + sizeof(void*)), newstr, strlen(newstr) + 1, 0);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::string str = "Hello Mate";

    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, GetCurrentProcessId());

    char newstr[] = "Goodbye m8";

    WriteExternalString(hProcess, (BYTE*)&str, newstr);

    cout << "string char array = " << str << endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```